# Check validity of RSA key pair

Tags: solution-verification, modular-arithmetic

I have the following RSA key pair:

$$(n,e) = (874444037, 43) $$

$$(n,d) = (874444037, 7) $$

How can I know I it is a valid key pair?

I cannot find $\phi(n) $ easily because n is large, thus I cannot check if $ 43 * 7$ mod $\phi(n) = 1$

Also $\phi(n)$ is always even, and 43 and 7 are both odd, so 2 is not a common factor. Are there any other characteristics I have to check? (It's a homework question but unfortunately without solution)

Comment: That number is quite small, really.  Easily factored, as [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factor+874444037).

Comment: I'm not allowed to use anything other but a simple calculator

Comment: Well, ok, but it's really clear that $43\times 7$ is far too small to be $1\pmod {\varphi(874444037)}$.  Did you mean something else?

Comment: @lulu I see your argument. But how would I formulate it without knowing phi(n)?

Comment: Yes, i meant to write $\varphi(n)$, edited now.  Same argument, though.  Simple bounds should show you that $\varphi(n)>43\times 7-1$.

Comment: For instance:  it is easy to check that no primes $<20$ divide $n$, so $\varphi(n)>22^2$.  Much, much greater, of course, but even this crude computation suffices.

Comment: It needs a 5 mod 6 factor and so we can test all 5 mod 6  primes up to 301 at most. Euler phi must be a multiple of 2,3, or 5 modulo to stand a chance.